# What was Walt doing between leaving Gray Matter and becoming a school teacher?

Tags: breaking-bad

There is a flashback scene in *Breaking Bad* in which young Walt and Skyler are buying their house. Walt sounds very optimistic about his career opportunities, suggesting that they should not buy a starter house, because they can "only go up". This is clearly the same house they are living in when Walt is 50.

Presumably Walt was not a high school teacher at that time yet, correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correct. [Walter](http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/Walter_White) was part of the 3 person team together with [Gretchen](http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/Gretchen_Schwartz) and [Elliot](http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/Elliott_Schwartz). He was, correction: is, a really smart chemist.

Back then the company wasn't worth that much. And because [Skyler](http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/Skyler_White) had a [baby](http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/Walter_White_Jr.) coming, Walter (as he explained to [Jessie](http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/Jesse_Pinkman) in [Buyout](http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/Buyout)) sold out his share of Gray Matter for a measly 5000 bucks. Big mistake, because a few years later, the company was worth billions, with a B.

**EDIT**

Apperently the story was completely different from what I perceived of it.

> Around 20 years ago, Walt worked in Application Labs ("Cancer Man"). He also worked in a chemical lab near Los Alamos, and met Skyler White, a hostess at that time, in a restaurant ("Cancer Man"). He moved to Albuquerque to work for Sandia Laboratories just prior to his firstborn ("Full Measure").
>   [Source](http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/Walter_White#Background_information)

I guess it's time for a Breaking Bad marathon.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is, what did Walt do *between* leaving Grey Matter, and teaching?

Comment: @Flimzy You're right, I found the actually history on the wikia. Clearly I was wrong all along. Time for a Breaking Bad marathon.

Comment: Now it makes sense to me - He moved to Albuquerque to work for Sandia Laboratories. Thx!

Comment: Then the question becomes: why did he leave Sandia to become a teacher?